# error while loading shared libraries: libg2c.so.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, libraries

I am trying to run a program built on a 32-bit architecture. But my machine is running the 64-bit Ubuntu 20.04 LTS version.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: AFAIK, `libg2c` was part of the (long deprecated) `g77` Fortran compiler package - how did you even obtain the (wrong) architecture of it?